# IOS - Como criar Célula customizada para TableView?

Tags: objective-c, mobile, xcode, uitableview, uitableviewcell

Quero fazer uma  célula customizada para minha TableView. Mas ela está apresentando problemas que não estou conseguindo resolver.
Ela funcionou normalmente quando fiz com a célula padrão, mas quando fiz customizada deu problema

Estava usando esta explicação como ajuda:
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Fiz minha célula desta forma..

## SimpleTableCell.xib e SimpleTableCell.h:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## SimpleTableCell.m

```
import "SimpleTableCell.h"

@interface SimpleTableCell ()
@end
@implementation SimpleTableCell

@synthesize nome = _nome;
@synthesize texto = _texto;
@synthesize data = _data;
@synthesize foto = _foto;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

A minha ViewController (Onde esta a TableView), esta desta forma.

## ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SimpleTableCell.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //________________________
    _tabela.dataSource = self;
    _tabela.delegate = self;
    //________________________
    //Na ViewDidLoad eu pego um Json e armazenando seus dados em uma lista (lista manda dados para célula)
    _users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSURLRequest *requisicao = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.meuSite.com.br/mural/listener.php?a=10"]];
    NSData *resposta = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requisicao
                                             returningResponse:nil                  
                                                         error:nil];
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: resposta options: nil error: &jsonParsingError];
    NSLog(@"result = %@", array.firstObject);
    int total = [array count];

    for (int x =0; x<total; x++) {
        [_users addObject:[array objectAtIndex:x]];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{//tamanho da lista
    return [_users count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"QUANDO COMPILO SÓ VEM ATÉ AQUI. . .");
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        NSLog(@"%d", 23);
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%d", 3);
    }
    NSDictionary * usuario = [_users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nome.text = [usuario objectForKey:@"nome"];
    cell.texto.text = [usuario objectForKey:@"texto"];
    cell.data.text = [usuario objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSString *img = @"http://diegocavalca.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/iphone_6_home_screen_hero.jpg";

    NSString *url_imagem = [NSString stringWithFormat:img];
    NSLog(@"%@", url_imagem);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:url_imagem];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         cell.foto.image =[UIImage imageWithData:data];
     }];
    return cell; 
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 100;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

## ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property NSMutableArray * users;
@property NSIndexPath * selecionado;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tabela;

@end
```

## Erro Apresentado. . .

-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x381cf588'
Caso alguém saiba como posso resolver isso, agradeço desde já.

Comment: O **nib** no caso, é o seu arquivo de interface, que pelo que eu entendi é o `MuralCell.xib`, mas sua classe tem o nome de `SimpleTableCell` e parece que o nome do arquivo é `MuralCellM.h`. Enfim, fiquei bem confuso em relação a estes nomes, e caso seja isso, esta é a razão. O erro diz que não consegue carregar um "nib" de nome *SimpleTableCell*.

Comment: Obrigado Paulo, vou corrigir isso agora mesmo!
caso consiga ou não aviso logo logo.

Comment: Tinha Razão, estava ocorrendo conflito entre os nome, já corrigi aqui e na pergunta também. Mas agora ele pega todas as informações do JSON e após isso, apresenta um erro informando o problema que atualizei na pergunta.

Comment: Coloca um "breakpoint for all execptions" no menu debug, ai ele para na linha em que ocorre o problema. Desse jeito fica difícil dizer o que pode ser.

Comment: Ele não esta mais apresentando erros, porem quando mando compilar, não mostra nenhuma informação na lista. A tela fica toda em branco. Estou trabalhando em cima disso pra ver se consigo resolver. A unica coisa que aparece após a execução eu deixei informado em (Erros Apresentado) na pergunta

Comment: Você precisa implementar o seguinte método também: `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { return 1; }`

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Luis, implementei na ViewController.m mas o problema mencionado antes permaneceu.

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com célula criando XIB, eu faço pelo InterfaceBuilder mesmo... você já tentou debugar seu código linha a linha para ver onde está logando esse error? Eu chutaria que é na hora de ler o json que não está achando alguma key, mas pode ser na hora de carregar o XIB também. Enfim, só debugando pra resolver.

Comment: Os JSON estão ok Henrique, estava fazendo isso agora. Vou tentar resolver isso hoje a noite. Amanha informo aqui caso tenha conseguido, de qualquer forma caso encontre alguma solução, informe que a noite eu volto aqui. Abraço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, o exemplo que peguei como base, era um exemplo antigo, não possuía nem uma storyboard, apenas arquivos .xib, decidi fazer um novo projeto e com ajuda de algumas páginas da internet, consegui fazer desta forma.

Utilizei esta página como base: http://www.makemegeek.com/custom-uitableviewcell-example-ios/

Alterei o nome SimpleTableCell para CustomCell.

ficou desta forma:

## CustomCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dataS;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *texto;

@end
```

## CustomCell.m

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize name,imageView,dataS;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {}
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

Alterei o nome da ViewController para MuralViewController.

Ficou desta forma:

## MuralViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MuralViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *ImageArray;//foodImageArray
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewObject;
@property NSMutableArray * users;

@end
```

## MuralViewController.m

```
#import "MuralViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface MuralViewController ()

@end

@implementation MuralViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ImageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image0.png", nil];
    //ADICIONADO . . .

    _users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];//Array de objétos json pegados de um link. . .

    NSURLRequest *requisicao = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.meuSite.com.br/mural/listener.php?a=50"]];

    NSData *resposta = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requisicao
                                             returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: resposta options: nil error: &jsonParsingError];

    NSDictionary *resultado = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:resposta
                                                              options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

    NSLog(@"result = %@", resultado);
    int total = [array count];
    for (int x =0; x<total; x++) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:x]);
        [_users addObject:[array objectAtIndex:x]];//Armazena na lista os dados json. . .
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];}

#pragma - mark UITableView Methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_users count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 130;//define o tamanho em que a célula vai aparecer. . .
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary * usuario = [_users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //ALOCA DADOS EM UMA STRING. . .    
    NSString *nome345 = [usuario objectForKey:@"nome"];
    NSString *data = [usuario objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSString *textok = [usuario objectForKey:@"texto"];

    nome345 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nome345];//Tive que sobreescrever, quando mandava direto dava eero no if logo abaixo. . .
    NSLog(@"%@", nome345);

    //ESCREVE DADOS NA CÉLULA. . .
    if([nome345 isEqualToString:@"<null>"]){//Se o nome for null, ele carrega a imagem no lugar no nome, assim nunca vai ter nome e imagem juntos. . .
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[ImageArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    }else{
        cell.Name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nome345];
    }

    cell.dataS.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data];
    cell.texto.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textok];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Desta forma ele esta funcionando bem, lembrando que tive que utilizar:

-Foundation.framework

-CoreGraphics.framework

-UIKit.framework

E também na .storyboard, adicionei à TableView os Outlets dataSource e delegate